# Validar campo após digitação

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-validator

Estou utilizando o [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/), a validação do formulario esta funcionando muito bem. Porém, eu queria que a validação do campo `nome` seja executada somente quando o usuário terminar de digitar.

A validação desse campo faz uma requisição `ajax` de forma síncrona, e isso faz dar umas travadas durante a digitação.

```js
$("#frmImovel").validator({
  disable: false,
  custom: {
   existingName: function($el) {
    var teste = "";
    $.ajax({
     url: 'https://www.hobbietech.com.br/VitrineImoveis/adm/data-remote-validations/nome_imovel_existente.php',
     datatype: 'json',
     data: {
      idImovel: $el.data("existingname"),
      nome: $el.val()
     },
     async: false,
     success: function (response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      if (response.result === false) {
       teste = response.mensagem;
      }
     }
    });
    
    return teste;
   }
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.hobbietech.com.br/VitrineImoveis/adm/js/validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="frmImovel" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="txtNome" class="control-label">Nome</label>
        <input id="txtNome" name="nome" class="form-control"
         data-existingname="0"
         placeholder="Nome do Imóvel" type="text"
         data-required-error="Por favor, informe o nome do imóvel!"
         data-remote-error="Já existe um imóvel com este nome!"
         required
        >
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar manipulando os eventos `keydown`, `keyup` e `focus`.

Eu só adiciono a validação `existingname` no `Bootstrap Validator` quando o usuário digitar ao menos uma letra e ficar 1 segundo sem digitar nada. Quando o usuário clicar em algum botão ou entrar no campo eu removo a validação.

```js
var typingTimer;

$("#frmImovel").validator({
  disable: false,
  custom: {
   existingName: function($el) {
    var teste = "";
    $.ajax({
     url: 'https://www.hobbietech.com.br/VitrineImoveis/adm/data-remote-validations/nome_imovel_existente.php',
     datatype: 'json',
     data: {
      idImovel: $el.data("existingname"),
      nome: $el.val()
     },
     async: false,
     success: function (response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      if (response.result === false) {
       teste = response.mensagem;
      }
     }
    });
    
    return teste;
   }
  }
 });
  
  $('#frmImovel #txtNome').keyup(function() {
      if ($('#myInput').val) {
       typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#frmImovel #txtNome').attr("data-existingname", 0);
        $('#frmImovel').validator('update');
        $('#frmImovel').validator('validate');
       }, 1000);
      }
     }).keydown(function() {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);
      $('#frmImovel #txtNome').removeAttr("data-existingname");
      $('#frmImovel').validator('update');
     }).focus(function() {
      $('#frmImovel #txtNome').removeAttr("data-existingname");
      $('#frmImovel').validator('update');
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.hobbietech.com.br/VitrineImoveis/adm/js/validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="frmImovel" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="txtNome" class="control-label">Nome</label>
        <input id="txtNome" name="nome" class="form-control"
         data-existingname="0"
         placeholder="Nome do Imóvel" type="text"
         data-required-error="Por favor, informe o nome do imóvel!"
         data-remote-error="Já existe um imóvel com este nome!"
         required
        >
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Chama a função de verificar o campo do "nome" somente quando o usuário clicar para fora do campo.

Use o "onblur" para fazer isso.

```
<input id="txtNome" onblur="myFunction()" name="nome" class="form-control"
                    data-existingname="0"
                    placeholder="Nome do Imóvel" type="text"
                    data-required-error="Por favor, informe o nome do imóvel!"
                    data-remote-error="Já existe um imóvel com este nome!"
                    required
                >
```

Comment: Não é bem isso, mas sua resposta me fez ter uma ideia e essa ideia funcionou, postei uma resposta de como consegui fazer.

Comment: Ué, então tudo bem hauhauhauahau